# Infinite spamming on messaging

Tags: python, telegram

In this loop, sometimes I get infinity spamming in telegram error with code request, that not equal 200 and that there is no records in log_file. Like looping on bot.send_message. And I don't get why.
But the code doesn't break, so I can't get any errors. Seems like "sleep" doesn't work sometimes, but how it can work randomly?

Most of the time, the code works properly

```
import time
import telebot
import requests
import datetime
import json
import os
from funcs import *
from varias import *
from pathlib import Path

if not os.path.exists('C:/pymon_logs'):
    os.makedirs('C:/pymon_logs')

log_file = path("api_log", "a")

while 1:
    try:
        request = str(requests.get("https://***"))
        
        if request == "<Response [200]>":
            time.sleep(5)

        elif request != "<Response [200]>":
            bot.send_message(chat_id, "API " + str(request)[1:-1])
            log_file.write(str(request)[1:-1] + " " + today + '\n')
            log_file.close()
            time.sleep(120)

    except requests.ConnectionError as e:
        bot.send_message(chat_id, "API Connection Error")
        log_file.write("API Connection Error" + " " + today + '\n')
        log_file.close()
        time.sleep(120)             

    except requests.Timeout as e:
        bot.send_message(chat_id, "API Timeout Error")
        log_file.write("API Timeout Error" + " " + today + '\n')
        log_file.close()
        time.sleep(120) 

    except requests.RequestException as e:
        bot.send_message(chat_id, "API huy znaet chto za oshibka")
        log_file.write("API huy znaet chto za oshibka" + " " + today + '\n')
        log_file.close()
        time.sleep(120)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: you have a `while 1: try: ... except: pass`. That's basically an infinite loop. Don't swallow exception.

Comment: In addition to @njzk2's comment, you should not convert requests.get() to a string. Try doing `request = requests.get(...)` then `if request.ok:` and `else:`  don't use an elif in this scenario.

Comment: You can check the response code without turning the request into a string with `request.status_code`, which returns and integer. From your code it seems like you're never opening `log_file`?

Comment: @Armadillan its opening path("api_log", "a") here with append flag

Comment: @njzk2 there is no error there, i used break and print before, but there is no problem

Comment: @sad_and_bored based on the accepted answer, I'm fairly confident that `log_file.write` throws an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't check response code by converting to string. It's not a good practice IMHO.

You should:

```py
request = requests.get("https://***")
```

and check by:

```py
if r.status_code == 200:
    ...
```

And this next line is unnecessary. Replace this code with `else`:

```py
elif request != "<Response [200]>":
```

But the main problem with your code, is you shouldn't close the file in an infinite loop. With your code, on the very first exception you are closing the file. If you close the file handle, you cannot write, so you will not be able to see anything in the log file.

And, after your code gets another non-200 response code, you try to write on a closed file, then throw another exception. This way, you skip the `sleep(120)` part, and throw again and again and again...

TL,DR;

Remove all the

```py
log_file.close()
```

parts.

Comment: if im using log_file.write(...)
and in this func does opening file,
it doesent open it every time?

Comment: no, a file stays open, as long as you haven't closed it.

Comment: and by the way, i'd expect you to use log_file = open(...) not log_file = path(...)

Comment: So https://codeshare.io/2KKebo here is my path func, it does openening file inside 
The main problem was not even in loging, because it was working, when messages not looping

Your corrections: r.status_code and else probably fixed this problem. Thanks!

btw i still dont understend the logic of this problem with messaging

Comment: Your path function seems ok. As I said trying to write on a closed file gives error. Good luck!...